# Find the minimum number of steps to change a sequence to another

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

We are given two oriented sequences,

for example `(+A-) (-B+) (+C-) (-D+) (+E-) and (+B-) (+C-) (-D+) (+E-) (+A-)`.

Notice that `(+A-)` means a oriented subsequence, where `'+'` means the head of subsequence and `'-'` means the tail. If `'1234'` is `(+A-)`, then `'4321'` is `(-A+)`, which is the reverse of `(+A-).`

**The goal is to find the minimum number of steps to change a sequence to another with only the operation of reverse.**

For example, we need to reverse once to change `(+A-)(+B-) to (-B+)(-A+).`

And we need to reverse twice to change `(+A-) (+B-) (+C-) to (-A+) (+B-) (-C+).`

The minimum number of steps to operate between the two sequence given at first is 3. Here is one way to do that:

> Step 0. (+A-) (-B+) (+C-) (-D+) (+E-)
>
> Step 1. **(+B-) (-A+)** (+C-) (-D+) (+E-)
>
> Step 2. (+B-) (-A+) **(-E+) (+D-) (-C+)**
>
> Step 3. (+B-) **(+C-) (-D+) (+E-) (+A-)**

---

My idea is that the problem may relates to sorting problem, but instead of swapping two individual element in a sequence, here we have to consider swapping two subsequence.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Maths assignment, belongs to http://maths.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your step 3 is not clear. I think you will need one more step there.

Comment: Your problem has a well-known name - edit distance. There is a known algorithm to solve it - the Wagner Fischer algorithm. Wikipedia will help you :)

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal. Sorry I didn't express it clearly. I mean reverse the last four subsequences in Step 2, and then we get the result in Step 3.

Comment: @Alex. Thanks so much for your hint! I will do a study on it right away!

Comment: @Raptor algorithms is on the boundary of math and computer science, isn't it? If all algorithms questions are off-topic here, why do we have the tag in the first place?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Read the FAQ if you have time

Comment: @Raptor Don't use the FAQ as an excuse not to understand accepted site practices. Also, "software algorithms" explicitly are on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could try is to consider a function g that counts all the places in the sequence where two adjacent elements are not joined correctly.

So in your original example with a target of:

```
Start (+B-) (+C-) (-D+) (+E-) (+A-) End
```

we consider each pair of elements in the original sequence:

```
Start (+A-) (-B+) (+C-) (-D+) (+E-) End ->
Start (+A-) Incorrect because Start should be followed by +B
(+A-) (-B+) Incorrect because A- should be followed by End
(-B+) (+C-) Incorrect because B+ should be followed by Start
(+C-) (-D+) Correct
(-D+) (+E-) Correct
(+E-) End   Incorrect because E- should be followed by +A
```

So this has a score of 4 incorrect.

Whenever you reverse a substring, you change the state of at most 2 adjacent elements, so at best the score will decrease by 2.

In your example we have:

Step 0. x (+A-) x (-B+) x (+C-) (-D+) (+E-) x Score 4

Step 1. (+B-) x (-A+) x (+C-) (-D+) (+E-) x  Score 3

Step 2. (+B-) x (-A+) (-E+) (+D-) (-C+) x Score 2

Step 3. (+B-) (+C-) (-D+) (+E-) (+A-) Score 0

As the original score was 4, we know for sure that at least 2 swaps are needed (as the score can decrease by at most 2 per step), and your solution uses 3 so we only need to check out alternatives where the score decreases by 2 on each step in order to rule out a better solution.

There is a well-known algorithm for doing this type of search and it is called [A star search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

For this type of search you need an admissible heuristic that never overestimates the distance to the goal.  I recommend you try solving your problem using the heuristic given by 0.5*g .